# Testing model classes in Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I need to test all model classes of my project. Here is one of the classes

```
public class TMyData{
    private mVar1;
    private mVar2;
    ...

    private TMyData(){
    }

    public static TMyData fromString(String str){
        ...
    }


    public String toString(){
        ...
    }


}
```

Simply, the test should be:

1) Create a random TMyData

2) Call toString

3) Call fromString

4) Check they are the same

The problem is to create the random TMyData. As the testing class is a separate one (TMyDataTest), I cannot do the following:

```
TMyData p = new TMyData();  //I can't, because its private
p.mVar1 = ...; // I can't because is also private
```

I don't want to change all my variables/methods visibilities just because of the testing... And I also don't want the user to have access to the private variables (no getters nor setters)

Many people must have had similar problems, as all projects have their own model. Which is the proper way to test it?

Comment: and where do mVars come from?

Comment: They come from another constructor that parses another object. This other object comes from an external library and I cannot create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can only see a solution by doing it with reflection.

```
Field f = tmydata.getClass().getDeclaredField("mVar1"); //NoSuchFieldException
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(tmydata,dataToSet);
```

Comment: After trying many different things, this is the best solution. Thanks